# Appending the pid number to unix filename using python

Tags: python

In shell script I create a filename with $$ extension like filename.$$ to append the pid no. I want to acheive the same in python.

How to create a filename.$$ in python ?

```
try:
    os.remove('/tmp/update_pid.ksh')
except OSError:
    pass

try:
    os.remove('/tmp/rollbackfile_pid.ksh')
except OSError:
    pass

fo = open('/tmp/update_pid.ksh','a')
fi = open('/tmp/rollback_pid.ksh','a')
```

In place of "pid" I want the pid number.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
os.remove('/tmp/update_%d.ksh' % os.getpid())
```